# elastic search phase_prefix query not working for first letter of second word

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query returns correct document (with movie_name = "star wars") for query = "s", "st", "sta","star", "star wa", "star wars" but not for "star w" returns 0 results.

This happens will all documents and queries, so want to know how to fix this and if there are any other alternatives for the same.

I am using elastic search 1.7. Thanks a lot in advance !

`"query": {
        "bool": {
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
          "should": [
            {
              "constant_score": {
                "query": {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "star w",
                    "type": "phrase_prefix",
                    "fields": [
                      "movie_name",
                      "movie_tags"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "boost": 2
              }
            },
            {
              "constant_score": {
                "query": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "movie",
                    "query": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "movie.cast",
                        "query": {
                          "match": {
                            "movie.cast.name": {
                              "query": "star w",
                              "type": "phrase_prefix"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          ],....`